# How to load a component in single parent router-outlet Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I have an Angular 4 application with **app.component.html** as -

```
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<app-topbar></app-topbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Two routes to 2 different components -

- Parent - `/test` to TestComponent
- Child - `/test/:id` to TestChildComponent

TestComponent is rendered in `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` of **app.component.html**.

I would like if TestChildComponent is also loaded into the same application outlet for the specified URL. Is this possible? Or, is there another way to structure it?

Comment: Aren't you mixing the concept of module and components in this TestModuleComponent? What's the content of `TestModuleComponent`

Comment: No, I'm just using it as an example component name not intended to be confused with Angular modules. (Changed to a different name)

Comment: ok, good. Have you gave a look into this [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview). It's made by the angular team to explain routing and module organization

Comment: estChildComponent is also loaded into the same application outlet for the specified URL. means can you please make it a bit more readable

Comment: @Custodio the URL you gave me leads to the main site (Plunker).

Comment: @RahulSingh I have specified the Child URL made it more readable.

Comment: my bad... here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FhAlHKsqR6EyV8EN8iYt?p=preview)